# Sorting of a foreach function asc

Tags: php, syntax, foreach, usort

i have searched and tried some of the solutions here, but cannot find the answer to solve my problem. I think i have to use usort to make below code result in ASC sorted array, but i dont know how to put in the syntax....
any help apprieciated...

```
<?php
//show menu items
$nav = $eshop->getNav();
foreach ($nav as $i => $btn) { ?>

        <li class="<?php if ($i == 0) echo 'first'; ?>"><a href="<?= $url . $btn['link'] ?>"   id="cat-<?= $btn['id'] ?>"><?= $btn['caption'] ?></a>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="title">Producten</span>
                    <ul>
    <?php
    //show products of this item
    foreach ($btn['products'] as $j => $prodBtn) { ?>

                        <li><a href="<?= $url . $prodBtn['link'] ?>"><?= $prodBtn['caption'] ?></a></li>
    <?php
        //10 products max
        if ($j >= 10) break;
    }
    ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span class="title">Merken</span>
                    <ul>
    <?php
    //show brands of this item
    foreach ($btn['brands'] as $j => $brandBtn) { ?>

                        <li><a href="<?= $url . $brandBtn['link'] ?>"><?= $brandBtn['caption'] ?></a></li>
    <?php
        //10 brands max
        if ($j >= 10) break;
    }
    ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

sorry i didnt get the indent piece,! 
but with above code no products are listed. I only get the sub-menus (products / brands / aplications)

So maybe some more info: menu shows categories, then on a category it shows products brands etc...to choose. when using sort function no products or anything is shown but the name of the sub-menu...
thanks
Stefan

edited code that is used

Comment: Please indent code correctly. By organizing code, one already solves half of the problems...

Answer (score 1):

Sort your array prior to the foreach() call.  As it's a multi-dimensional array, you probably do need a special sort (usort is user-definable, there are plenty of others).

```
sort($nav); // or usort, ksort, $foosort ....

foreach ($nav as $i => $btn) {
    //foo
```

Comment: Obviously, the usort() call would be:

    usort($nav,"my_sorting_function_name");

Comment: i know got the below code, but no products are shown. if i put it before the foreach nav code it completely reverses my menu...any ideas?
<?php

usort($btn,
    function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    });
  //show products of this item
  foreach ($btn['products'] as $j => $prodBtn) { ?>
  
       <li><a href="<?= $url . $prodBtn['link'] ?>"><?= $prodBtn['caption'] ?></a></li>

Comment: I wouldn't use strcmp; at least, I think not.  Show your data; perhaps a PasteBin?  It looks as if you want to compare the "Caption" member of your button array.  What do those look like?

Comment: Hi Kkinsey, i edited the code in the main question...this is the original code used in the page to show the menu's....(and the products) Hope you have a hint or answer for me as i am pulling my hair over this. (i only want the products, brands to be sorted ASC)...

Comment: Stefani, I'm sorry, but without data I've not much clue how to help any further (in other words, I can't sort what I can't see).  That's why I suggested a PasteBin or some place where we could see sample data.